# Nginx reverse proxy stalls on large files

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

**My setup:**
Nginx reverse proxy which proxy's traffic from my domain to a Synology NAS

`https://photo.domain.com => Synology Photos (local IP)`

But, when trying to upload large files (=videos), the upload fails.
Connecting directly to the local IP works just fine - so: Somehow the proxy fails.

In /etc/nginx/nginx.conf i have specified:

```
client_max_body_size 0;
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
```

Also tested with

```
client_header_timeout 300s;
client_body_timeout 300s;
keepalive_timeout 300s;
send_timeout 300s;
```

Upload still fails. Advice or hints are much appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this with:

```
client_max_body_size 0;
proxy_read_timeout 1800;
proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
proxy_send_timeout 1800;
proxy_request_buffering off;
```

Think it was the last line that did the job :)